# Title of movie in French about lip-reading woman who steals money from a criminal

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a noir-ish movie a while ago, **probably made in 2000 or later**, that involved a romance/partnership between a deaf woman and a man.

One of them (I think the woman) worked in a bar. The woman was able to read lips, which enabled her to spy on and steal money from a criminal who was storing money in an apartment. One of the scenes took place on a rooftop overlooking the criminal's room.

I'm pretty sure **the movie was in French**, and I had the feeling it was from Quebec rather than France or any other French-speaking country.

I had no luck searching for the movie using keywords such as "read lips", "bar", "criminal". Any ideas as to the title of the movie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description sounds like the film [*Sur mes lèvres*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_My_Lips_(film)) (titled *Read My Lips* in English).  The film was made in France and released in 2001. The plot involves the a nearly deaf woman, Carla (portrayed by [Emmanuelle Devos](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0222922/)), who participates in the robbery of a night-club owner.  As described in Wikipedia:

> Paul convinces her to help him – by using her lip-reading skills – to
>   rob Marchand, a nightclub owner to whom he owes a lot of money and for
>   whom he is working at night to pay off the debt.